# How to run LogOut Action In Home Controller that can not run by ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My Home Controller Like this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{


    ....


    [ActionName("Login")]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(string UserName, string Password)
    {
        try
        {
            var query = user_Repository.Login(UserName, Password);

            if (query != null)
            {


                Session["UserName"] = query.UserName;
                Session["IsAdmin"] = query.IsAdmin;

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "News");
            }
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "نام كاربري يا رمز عبور صحيح نمي باشد";
            return View();



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = " خطا!!! ";
            return View();
        }
    }


    public ActionResult LogOut()
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["user"] != null)
        {
            var user = new HttpCookie("user")
            {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                Value = null
            };
            Response.SetCookie(user);
            Response.Cookies.Clear();

        }
        if(Session["UserName"] != null)
        {
            Session["UserName"] = null;
            Session["IsAdmin"] = null;
        }
        Session.Clear();
        return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index");
    }
}
```

When i Use ActionLink in _Layout to Run Logout Action in Home Controller , this ActionLink Instead of executing Logout Action, Login will be executed!!!
My ActionLink Like this:

```html
  @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOut", "Home")
```

where is my wrong??? why @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOut", "Home") run Login Action????????????????????

i use this code for run that LogOut Action in my _Layout and this code work Correct...

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form" }))
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                        <input type="submit" value="خروج" class="btn btn-primary" />
                                    }
```

This is a text that stackOverflow lets me send the text because stackOverflow says i should give more explanations and say "it looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"!!!  i dont have any more detail.... i explain all of that ;)

Comment: @mjwills hi, Nothing happens, just wirite [HttpPost] for test that run this action by actionLink or not ,I saw that it did not run

Comment: @mjwills I cleaned up that Attribute

Comment: Did you put the debugger and run sequentially action on which call is being executed? It is possible that after logout action is being redirected to Login action

Comment: @AhsamAslam thank yoou for your comment.. yes put debugger but at all do not run the LogOut Action And just Run Login Action ,,, !!!

Comment: ok just try to inspect that link is in google console inspect Element that what link is being generated with the ActionLink Attribute then throw that link manually on the browser search bar.. hopefully you will get the error this way

Comment: @seyyedMorteza Glad to help. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers. For more information, take a look at our stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

Do not put your `Logout` action in a `Form`. Your `ActionLink` should work correctly if you have given the correct parameters to it.

Your `ActionLink` would look like this:

```
<a href='@Url.Action("LogOut", "Home")'>Log Out</a>
```

And your `Controller` action result would look like this:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    if (Request.Cookies["user"] != null)
    {
        var user = new HttpCookie("user")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
            Value = null
        };
        Response.SetCookie(user);
        Response.Cookies.Clear();

    }
    if(Session["UserName"] != null)
    {
        Session["UserName"] = null;
        Session["IsAdmin"] = null;
    }
  //Session.Abandon();
  //Session.Clear();
  return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
}
```

Use `RedirectPermanent` if the resource has been moved permanently and will no longer be accessible in its previous location. Most browsers will cache this response and perform the redirect automatically without requesting the original resource again.

Use `Redirect` if the resource may be available in the same location (URL) in the future.
So in your case `Redirect` would be the option since this would be hit by any user logging out of your system.

`Session.Abandon` removes all the objects stored in a Session. If you do not call the Abandon method explicitly, the server removes these objects and destroys the session when the session times out. It also raises events like Session_End

`Session.Clear` removes all keys and values from the session-state collection.

Think of it like this: Session.Clear can be compared to removing all items from a cart, while Session.Abandon is more like abandoning the entire cart itself.

You can use either of these two methods for destroying or clearing your Session. Currently you are doing a `Clear` explicitly by assigning your `UserName` and `IsAdmin` to null.